# How do I copy the rows of which certain cells contain text, and paste them to another location?

Tags: excel, vba

Some cells in column J contain texts and the others are empty.
I want to 1. find all the rows where column J contains text 2. copy these rows 3.paste them somewhere else (in the same order as the initial table)

```
Sub org1()

Dim a As Range
For Each a In Range("j2:j500")
    If Not a.Value = "" Then
       a.EntireRow.Copy
       a.Offset(100, 0).Insert
    End If
Next a

End Sub
```

error

Comment: Just filter out the blanks and then copy/paste visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do a structure like that. Simply filter the column excluding the blank cells, then copy the filtered column to wherever you want. If you don't know how to do the filter in vba, record a macro and do the process.

If you don't want the column filtered after that, just remove any filters afterwards with Sheets("YourSheet").AutoFilterMode = False

Comment: I cannot do that because there's data in the cell above the one next to the cells with text. For example, if J2 has contents, E1 has a value but J1 would be empty and if I use the filter, E2 would not be presented